# 100 ArcSDE layers in one Map service - ArcGIS Server 10.3

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase

I am doing my very first WebGIS application with ArcGIS server using ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17. I have to bring 100 layers in my webgis application as REST service from Oracle DB. To do that whether can we publish 100 layers as one map service or each layer as one service i.e 100 map service or group the layers as 10 datasets and publish as 10 map service. please suggest that which is the efficient way to publish those 100 layers in ArcGIS server.

Comment: Have you considered using [ArcGIS Portal Data Store](http://server.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/what-is-arcgis-data-store.htm)?

Comment: I usually use one layer per service to make it easier to update, but 100 may be better as 10 services showing 10 layers. I can see a nightmare with checkboxes, transparency, popups, etc. Not to mention, all that data going to a clients browser may crash it or make it very slow.. I have a simple Oracle REST service of 10k points and it will crash Firefox all the time.  You might be better breaking it down to separate maps to limit the data.

Comment: There is a good discussion in this Q&A: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17486/lots-of-layers-in-one-or-multiple-services-and-why Personally I find breaking a large map service into groups makes for the best solution. Individual map services per layer leads to to much overhead, IMO. But how the map services will be consumed has a big impact on what approach will work.

Comment: Id argue this is a duplicate of the Q mentioned by @Dowlers ?

Answer (score 2):

If services are created with the intention of WMS only then you can get away with more layers in a service. However, if you plan to utilize WFS functionality be careful. The more services being called as WFS can result in poor server and client performance.

I would suggest opening a dialogue with Esri Support if you start to experience a loss of functionality.

Comment: Thanks Michael. We are using only WMS service in our application.