# MXD Layer Management When Publishing Services with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, feature-class, mxd, publishing, services

Currently have an MXD with 130 layers in the table of contents. All of these layers need to exist in the service when it gets published each time an update is performed. I'm in the understanding that when a service is published to ArcGIS for Server/Enterprise, that it does a complete replacement of the service with the new service. Is there a way to just add to the existing service?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to remove all 130 layers in the MXD that I don't need since they already exist in the service. I just want to push the new layers up and add them to the current service. This is a rolling update process, so eventually, I will have 500+ layers, and I don't want to manage all that in the MXD each time I update.

How can I do this? What do I need to do with the MXD and/or GDB to accomplish this?

EDIT
The 130 layers (stored in a GDB as FCs) exist in an MXD and represent county level health data. Every layer has 3140 or so records with various fields. No application of symbology at the MXD level as that is being done at the service endpoint level. The service exists to feed an application tool where users search for data, select it and display a thematic map (only one at a time). There will be no intention to show two or more at the same time.

Comment: 130 is a large number of layers for a single service, sufficiently large that you can expect performance degradation when accessing the layer list in JSON.  You cannot add to an existing service. It sounds like you need to restructure how you publish data, using multiple services in families where possible. But this will only be possible if the layers will be used selectively, and not in conjunction with each other.

Comment: Haven't experienced any degradation (yet). I can't be the only user to need a large number of layers in a single service, so would be curious about the management aspect.

Comment: Similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17486/lots-of-layers-in-one-or-multiple-services-and-why

Comment: There's some nice stuff in that post, but it's also 7 years old. There's also not much in term of management strategies for 100's of layers in a MXD.

Comment: This question is on a slippery slope. As asked, the goal is impossible, so you need to change it. But asking for advice on managing massive numbers of layers is likely to cross over into an *opinion-based* discussion. To make this less subjective you'll need to add many more details on the nature of the layers and how they are used.